# Disable Kerio control nat for incomming connections

Tags: networking, nat

How can I disable NAT for incoming connection in kerio?
I made a traffic rule as follows:

```
Source:any
Destination: "my valid ip"
Service: http,https,dns
Action:allow
Translation:MAP X.X.X.X
```

X.X.X.X is a local invalid IP addess.

For all incoming connection to my web server I receive my valid IP as Source Ip Address.
How can I know actual Source Address?

Answer (score 0):

When go under translation for traffic rules unchecking source and destination nat will disable nat.

But in your setting above it seems  you like anyone to connect to https, http, dns service.

Do you run a web server?
If you run web server and want anyone to allow using web service you only need http and https not dns

Source IP address in kerio control is IP address from any client( external web traffic or internal ip's or specific IP).  Source ip address depend upon whom you like to give access to web services on your server.

Eg: If you want anyone can access(Incoming connection) your  Https, http you can use **any**. Or if you know who can only access web service you can get their public ip address like 8.8.8.8 and use in source ip address.